# BLDC motor sensors are reading High while no current is flowing through motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, hall-effect

I am trying to get a sensored bldc motor to spin by building my own ESC. I have the complete circuit built and working perfectly, but i'm having trouble with the sensors.

Recently something weird has happened. The sensors are rotating through the 6 phases as I rotate the motor by hand, but what's weird is that I completely unplugged the bldc motor phase wires from the power source (while still powering the sensor pins with 5 volts) and when I continue to rotate the shaft the sensors continue to rotate through the 6 phases. It should be reading LOW for all sensors no matter where I rotate the motor because there should be no current flowing through the motor, but the sensors are still detecting a high signal.

Something else that is weird is normally the 6 phases that your sensors detect are `100, 010, 001, 110, 011, 101`, but my sensors are detecting `111, 110, 100, 000, 001, 011` as I rotate the shaft. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please can we have link to your motor?

Comment: Or are your Hall sensor similar to this? 3-Phase Brushless DC Motor Control with Hall Sensors - Oleg Basovych, Dialog Semiconductor, 2018jun26
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/industry-articles/3-phase-brushless-dc-motor-control-with-hall-sensors/

Comment: @tlfong01 here is the link to my motor: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07PNMYHFT?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details.

Comment: Your link is in Chinese. I guess this an English equivalent: Electric Skateboard Motor, 6374 DC 36V Motor Hall Sensor, High Torsion Mountain: Remote Control Car Outer Rotor with Connector Terminals for Skateboard - Hyuduo US$147
https://www.amazon.com/Electric-Skateboard-Mountain-Connector-Terminals/dp/B08MZFQJKR

Comment: Honestly have no idea why its Chinese for you cause its English for me haha. But yeah thats pretty much the same motor what you have there.

Comment: Ah, I am using Chinese Windows 10 Chrome browser which directs me to the Chinese website, and I could not find a direction to any English version of the site. Anyway, this is the Hall sensor details: Hyuduo 6374 Motor Hall Sensor
https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71mgYfVTsCL._AC_SX466_.jpg

Comment: I am not surprised that your sensors are detecting 111, 110, 100, 000, 001, 011, as long as  there are six unique 3-bit signals (One-hot encoding, as explained by @DKNguyen),  when the little permanent magnets pass the Hall sensors.

Comment: As in other question, the sensors don't record current in the motor. They are now doing what they should.

Answer (score 3):

They are sensing the magnetic field, not the current, to detect the position of the magnetic poles. It doesn't make any sense to sense current because current doesn't tell you the relative positions of the rotor and stator poles. What did you think the sensors were supposed to do? (this isn't meant to be rhetorical, I want to know)

> Something else that is weird is normally the 6 phases that your sensors detect are `100, 010, 001, 110, 011, 101`, but my sensors are detecting `111, 110, 100, 000, 001, 011` as I rotate the shaft.
> Does anyone know why this is happening?

It is using one-hot encoding which means only one bit changes between adjacent states. That's because in an unclocked system, you cannot rely on two bits to transition at *exactly* the same time. The result is that it will momentarily stutter on an intermediary state that was never meant to be which can obviously cause issues.

Comment: I understand that they aren't measuring current, but without current there wouldn't be a magnetic field. So how are they sensing a magnetic field if no current is flowing?

Comment: @Trev347 Are you forgetting about the permanent magnets?

Comment: I remembered those, but I assumed the sensors would only sense the electric magnets. If they sense both permanent and electric magnets then how do you know what phase you are in cause the permanent and electric magnets would get mixed?

Comment: A magnetic field is a magnetic field. The sensors can't tell the difference. I am unsure of the specifics but the sensors either need to be positioned appropriately in the motor so they are only sensitive to the field of the permanent magnets and positioned or you ignore the sensors that you know are picking up the coil magnetic field (since you know which coils are energized).

Comment: Yes that's what I assumed the bldc motor would be doing. But since thee sensors are sensing high signals even though there is no current running through the electric magnets doesn't that mean they are sensing the permanent magnet?

Comment: @Trev347 It's not clear what you mean when you say "the sensors are sensing high". You mean they are all outputting a HI signal simultaneously? I would expect the sensors to require power to function properly and sensors may output either HI or LO depending on when they detect a magnetic field. It depends on the sensor.

Comment: I am powering the sensors with 5 volts from my arduino, but the 3 phase wires are not connected to any power. And what I mean by "sensing high" is they are outputting a HIGH signal as I rotate the motor by hand.

Comment: So the sensors start out at 000 (0 meaning LOW output, and 1 meaning HIGH output), then I rotate the motor slightly and it moves to 001, then rotate it more and it goes to 011, then rotate it more 111, and more 110, etc.

Comment: So it's using one hot encoding and sensing the PM magnets.

Comment: Okay I think i'm finally getting this. So since the sensors are detecting the permanent magnets location, not the electro magnet locations, I need to program the phases based off pm locations?

Comment: @Trev347 I've never met a sensored motor that outputs 111 or 000 and actually works. you should probably have a look at sensor placement and pull ups if you're getting 111 or 000.

Comment: @Bryan I thought it was weird I was getting that too, but as I was spinning it around it was very consistent switching between the outputs so I don't think it's a problem. But IDK maybe i'm wrong? I'll keep this post updated if I get it to work.

Comment: @Trev347 as long as the two new illegal states 010 and 101 never appear its still workable. also to answer you comment question above: "I need to program the phases based off pm locations?" indeed you do. my first six stepper used a simple switch case statement based off the hall values read from the port, each case assigned a different pattern of pwm, off and ground to the phases.

Comment: @Bryan I haven't seen those 2 illegal states yet so I think it should be fine. I'm trying to program it now so we will see what happens.